# adjacency matrix map manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

0

I'm making a simple text based adventure game. My code uses an adjacency matrix as a map. I would like to navigate the map by direction ex(N,E,S,W) my current attempt can only navigate via the name of the location

current output

You are currently in Foyer.

From this location, you could go to any of the following:

```
 Living Room
```

Where would you like to go? Living Room

You are currently in Living Room.

From this location, you could go to any of the following:

```
 Foyer

 Bedroom 2

 Powder Room

 Kitchen
```

Where would you like to go? -__________________________________________________

I would like an output like

You are currently in Foyer.

From this location, you could go to any of the following:

```
 South
```

Where would you like to go? South

You are currently in Living Room.

From this location, you could go to any of the following:

```
 North

 West

 South

 East
```

Where would you like to go?

```
import pygame

Inventory = []
names = ["Foyer", "Living Room", "Bedroom 2", "Full Bath", "Bedroom 3","Powder Room","Dinning", "Home Office", "Kitchen","Walkin Closet", "Hallway", "Bedroom1", "Sitting Room","Balcony", "Storage", "Garage", "Supply Closet", "Utility Closet", "Front Yard", "Sidewalk"]
graph = [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
directions =["North", "East", "South", "West"]

curr_location = "Foyer"
while True:
    print("You are currently in ", curr_location, ".", sep = '')
    print()
    exits = []
    print("From this location, you could go to any of the following:")
    indx_location = names.index(curr_location)
    for each in range(len(graph[indx_location])):
        if graph[indx_location][each] == 1:
            print("\t", names[each])
            exits.append(names[each])
    print()
    next_location = input("Where would you like to go? ")
    if not (next_location in exits):
        print()
        print("You cannot go this way.")
    else:
        curr_location = next_location
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `North`, `South`, `East`, `West` to `exits` conditionally if it's possible to move in that direction?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: @user4378959 an adjacency matrix doesn't have a concept of directions between nodes, I believe you need a different data structure if you want to navigate that way.